# How can I find out the IP address from which a user logged in?

Tags: login, command, history, deleted-files

We have two RHEL 6.4 64-bit boxes in our environment. They are accessed remotely via putty.

The password of user `ABC` on one RHEL box is shared by multiple users.
User `ABC` logged into server from putty from some IP address and ran `rm -rf *`.

I need to know the culprit IP address. Is this feasible?

Comment: Welcome to [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)! Your question has been reformatted. Please make sure to use a very specific title (the most important bit of your question). Also, please specify how the user logged in (e.g. `ssh`?) You could use a [tag](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags) if you want.

Comment: note that `rm -rf *` on its own is not a completely dangerous command on its own - context of where it was run is more important...  also shared passwords is a no-no.  Use SSH Key Authentication if you want a more secure environment (and don't share passwords and phrases)

Comment: If the rm was in /home/ABC then `.bash_history` should have been left untouched (since * does not match "." files). The rm should still be in there. Get users to tell you what commands they gave, and you might be able to find who did the login before the rm, giving you an approximate time for the rm.

Comment: if you have selinux enabled, you may find some (innocent) commands that were denied in the selinux logs. they may give clues as to when expected files were first missing.  similarly, look for sudo or su commands that might have been tried and denied, in the /var/log/secure and /var/log/audit/ logs.